# How to protect variable name inside shell arithmetic?

Tags: bash, shell, variable, arithmetic

Variables can be protected with curly braces.

```bash
Mynewvar=1
echo $Mynewvar
1
echo ${Mynewvar}
1
```

However I can no longer protect them when inside shell arithmetic.

```bash
Mynewvar=1
echo $((Mynewvar+9))
10
echo $(({Mynewvar}+9))
```

```
bash: {Mynewvar}+9: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{Mynewvar}+9")
```

What is the right way to enclose variable names when it is inside shell arithmetic?

Comment: Your example doesn't show a valid reason to need this, do you have an example of a need for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: protect from what? Why/how is `$((Mynewvar+9))` a "wrong" way?

Comment: The braces are only needed if you want to apply [some transformation using parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or if you need to separate the variable from surrounding text. Some style guides suggest braces. However inside an arithmetic expression, a "bare" variable name cannot be surrounded by braces, as you've discovered.

Comment: Also note that this "protection" does not extend to preventing word splitting or filename expansion: if `myvar="*"` then `echo "$myvar"` and `echo ${myvar}` give different results. Similarly when `myvar="hello world"` and `printf '%s\n' "$myvar"` and `printf '%s\n' ${myvar}`

Comment: It is `echo $(( ${Mynewvar} + 9 ))`: you need one `$` for the `$(( ... ))` construct, and another `$` for the variable expansion. That's just standard syntax. But as others note, `$(( ... ))` only does arithmetic, so inside, shell interprets any word as a variable name reference.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you would want to use curly brackets around a variable to "protect" it is so that you can use it adjacent to other characters without them being interpreted as the variable name.  For example:

```
$ n=1
$ echo $nx

# there is no variable named nx so this prints nothing however
$ echo "${n}x"
1x
```

Any valid arithmetic operator will not be interpreted as a variable name so there is no need for curly brackets if you are simply doing something like `$((n+1))`.

However if you did want to concatenate two or more variables together you could use the `$` expansion within the arithmetic expansion, for example:

```
$ n=1
$ x=1
$ echo $(($n$x+1))
12
```